# PHP - Send Email, compare database current timestamp(reminder)send mail before one day and one hour to user

Tags: php, email, date, datetime

I'm trying to send  autoresponder mail for all user. 
In database field name coursedate(current timestamp) . I need to send the mail one day before the course date and one hour before cause time.

For example

> coursedate: 2015-05-25
>
> I need send mail on 2015-05-24 (before 24 hours)
>
> and before one hour on (2015-05-25)

How to do in php or mysql query

Comment: sounds great. do you have a question?

Comment: use `crontab -e`, then write command to fire your script

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need crontab. Write your normal php for doing the operation and then fire it at scheduled time using crontabs.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 0):

You need a cronjob, and according to the timestamp of registration, the sql query could be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (coursedate + INTERVAL 1 DAY) = NOW()
```